# I want to Use Y and N keyboard buttons to confirm a dialog popup

Tags: c#

I want to Use Y and N keyboard buttons to confirm a dialog popup. i.e use these keyboard buttons to press a winform button instead of using the mouse to click it. C#

[image]

Comment: Yes you can do that... did you write any code for this? can you share that code here? What issue you are facing ?

Comment: Is it Winforms or WPF? maybe is it web? Consider checking the help section and the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the event that triggers when you hit the Y or N. One of those events is "keypress". See more about this at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress

Comment: What if this was a non-winforms related aplication?

Answer (score 0):

I have done before capturing the event manager for capturing the input.

Put below code at startup:

`EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Window), Keyboard.KeyUpEvent, new KeyEventHandler(PressedNumber), true);`

On `PressedNumber` method:-

```
private void PressedNumber(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       // Validate if allow to use Yes No e.g. if (allowListener) {}
        var isLegit = e.Key == Key.Y || e.Key == Key.N;
        if (isLegit)
        {
                if (e.Key == Key.Y)
                {
                    // DO IF YES
                }
                else if (e.Key == Key.N)
                {
                    // DO IF NO
                }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string error = $"Error at pressed number event manager. Ex-{ex.Message}";

    }
}
```

If the dialog is your own custom dialog, you can also listen for keydown event when the popup is loaded.

1. For Windows Forms, you may refer to [Handle Keyboard Input at the
   Form Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-handle-keyboard-input-at-the-form-level)
2. For WPF, you may refer to [WPF KeyDown Event
   Handler](https://www.dotnetperls.com/keydown-wpf)